# std::copy with return values - Better way to prevent "expression: string iterators incompatible"?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have a getter to return a `std::string` and want to copy it to an `char array`.
My first attempt was crashing the application: `expression: string iterators incompatible`

```
std::copy(getString().begin(), getString().end(), array);
```

I solved it by adding a temporary variable:

```
std::string temp = getString();
std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), array);
```

Is there any better way than using a temporary variable or changing the return type to a pointer (did not test it but would assume this would also work)?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `getString()` return?

Comment: Bet it returns a temporary string; therefore the begin and end iterators are iterating different strings.

Comment: @BenSteffan As Richard mentiond it just returns an `std::string` which is a member of an object.

Comment: If you do not want to return a pointer or reference then you are stuck with passing by value and having to create the temporary.

Comment: @honiahaka10: Read Richard's comment again. It explains what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @honiahaka10 If it's a member of the object, and you don't want to allow it to be changed, just return a const reference. `std::string const & getString() const { return someMemberString; }` This will fix your issue as well as avoid making temporary copies in other situations.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I already knew what the problem was I am just searching for a better solution than mine.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks thats a great solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what return type `getString()` has. There are a few options:

`std::string getString();`

`const std::string& getString();`

`std::string& getString();`

Ideally we don't what to care as that interface may change in future (it sounds today as if you're not sure about it). It would be helpful if we didn't have to rework client code in the unhappy event of an interface change.

So rather than a temporary, take a const reference:

```
const std::string& temp = getString();
std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), array);
```

It may surprise you to learn that if `getString` actually returns a string copy, it's lifetime will last as long as the reference `temp`.

If it returns a reference, the code still works.

As of c++14, it's valuable to be more generic:

```
auto&& temp = getString();
std::copy(std::begin(temp), std::end(temp), array);
```

`getString()` can now return either an object or a reference of any type that supports iterators of `value_type` `char`

Comment: Wouldn't the `auto&& temp` approach be just as valuable in C++11?

Comment: Thank you for the possibilities! I just changed my return type from `std::string` to `const std::string&` like @cdhowie mentioned and it just works fine!